# i am just learning android studio,whenever i try to use startactivity(intent),from my "signup_activ" activity,the app crashes

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

the app crashes when i click the button on signup_activ to start userdetail_activ,if i swithc to some other activity istead , the app runs fine

this is my manifest file.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".login_activ"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".signup_activ"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".userdetail_activ"
        android:parentActivityName=".signup_activ" >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".userdetail_activ2" />
    <activity android:name=".infopage_activ"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

stack,after the app crash.

```
 AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.ozairmansuri.myapplication, PID: 1986
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ozairmansuri.myapplication/com.example.ozairmansuri.myapplication.userdetail_activ}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:118)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:152)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:200)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:184)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:518)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:189)
                                                                                          at com.example.ozairmansuri.myapplication.userdetail_activ.<init>(userdetail_activ.java:22)
                                                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

signup_activ

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class signup_activ extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_activ);
    }

    public void UserDet_Switch() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(signup_activ.this, userdetail_activ.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }

    public void Signup(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
        String A = editText.getText().toString();
        String B = editText2.getText().toString();
        String C = editText3.getText().toString();

        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (!isValid_pass(B, C, errorList)) {                                //checking whether password is valid

            for (String error : errorList) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        List<String> errorList2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (!isValid_usern(A,errorList2)){                                    //checking whethe user name is valid
            for (String error : errorList2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        SQLhelper dbh =new SQLhelper(this) ;
        if(dbh.checkUser(A,B)== true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"user alredy exists",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        dbh.addUser(A,B);                                                       //adding the user to database table 1
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "account created",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //// TODO: 28-09-2017 intent switch activity (userdetil activity)
        UserDet_Switch();
        return;

    }

    //function to check userncme

    public static boolean isValid_usern(String usern,List<String> errorList){


        Pattern lowerCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[a-z ]");
        Pattern digitCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[0-9 ]");
        errorList.clear();

        boolean flag=true;
        if (usern.length() < 8) {
            errorList.add("user name lenght must have alleast 8 character !!");
            flag=false;
        }


        if (!lowerCasePatten.matcher(usern).find()) {
            errorList.add("user name must have atleast one lowercase character !!");
            flag=false;
        }
        if (!digitCasePatten.matcher(usern).find()) {
            errorList.add("user name must have atleast one digit character !!");
            flag=false;
        }
        return  flag;
    }

    //function to check password

    public static boolean isValid_pass(String passwordhere, String confirmhere, List<String> errorList) {



        Pattern lowerCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[a-z ]");
        Pattern digitCasePatten = Pattern.compile("[0-9 ]");
        errorList.clear();

        boolean flag=true;

        if (!passwordhere.equals(confirmhere)) {
            errorList.add("password and confirm password does not match");
            flag=false;
        }
        if (passwordhere.length() < 8) {
            errorList.add("Password lenght must have alleast 8 character !!");
            flag=false;
        }


        if (!lowerCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
            errorList.add("Password must have atleast one lowercase character !!");
            flag=false;
        }
        if (!digitCasePatten.matcher(passwordhere).find()) {
            errorList.add("Password must have atleast one digit character !!");
            flag=false;
        }

        return flag;

    }

    }
```

userdetail_activ

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class userdetail_activ extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_HEIGHT = "height";
    public static final String EXTRA_WEIGHT = "weight";
    public static final String EXTRA_GENDER = "gender";
    RadioButton rb;
    RadioGroup rg ;
    Boolean gend =null;
    int A,B;
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userdetail_activ);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    }
    public void rb_click(View view){                                     //radio button function
        int radioButtonid = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
         rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioButtonid);
    if(radioButtonid == (R.id.radioButton2)) gend=true;                    //male is true
        else gend = false;                                                  //female is false
        return;
    }

    public void continue_userdetail(View view){
        A = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        B = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
        if(gend == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please select gender",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, userdetail_activ2.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_HEIGHT,A);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_WEIGHT,B);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_GENDER,gend);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
```

Never call methods that you inherit from `Activity` until after `super.onCreate()` has been called, unless documented otherwise.

Never call `findViewById()` until after the widgets exist, such as being created via a call to `setContentView()`.

Move the initialization of these two fields until after `setContentView()` is called in `onCreate()`.